# Is it possible to ask Mathematica to give/find this largest (absolute value) argument of $\cosh$ in the expression?

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, filtering

I have the expression `exp` in terms of `Cosh` functions:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
exp = a Cosh[
     2 Sqrt[3] (-8 + 
        Sqrt[3])] + (4 - (12 b (b (6 - (3 b (b - 4 s))/s^2) - 4 s))/
       s^2) Cosh[Sqrt[3] (-5 + Sqrt[3])]
   + (96 b (3 b^2 + s^2) Cosh[Sqrt[3] (-3 + Sqrt[3])])/s^3 - 
   4 (-1 - (3 b^2)/s^2)^2 Cosh[2 Sqrt[3] (-3 + Sqrt[3])] + 
   16 (-1 + (9 b^4)/s^4) Cosh[2 Sqrt[3] (-2 + Sqrt[3])] - 
   24 (-1 - (3 b^2)/s^2)^2 Cosh[
     Sqrt[3] (-1 + Sqrt[3])] - (32 (9 b^4 - 6 b^2 s^2 + s^4) Cosh[
        Sqrt[3] (-1 + Sqrt[3])]^2)/s^4;
```

**Question.** Actually, my original expression contains many more items than this simple chosen part. I want to find/know the largest argument of `Cosh` in the expression; I mean to find the argument whose absolute value is the largest. For example, here, checking numerically I see that the first term has the largest argument in absolute value.

```
{2 Sqrt[3] (-8 + Sqrt[3]), Sqrt[3] (-5 + Sqrt[3]), 
  Sqrt[3] (-3 + Sqrt[3]), 2 Sqrt[3] (-3 + Sqrt[3]), 
  2 Sqrt[3] (-2 + Sqrt[3]), Sqrt[3] (-1 + Sqrt[3]), 
  Sqrt[3] (-1 + Sqrt[3])} // N

(* {-21.7128, -5.66025, -2.19615, -4.3923, -0.928203, 1.26795, 1.26795} *)
```

Is it possible to ask Mathematica to give/find this largest argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
exp = a Cosh[
     2 Sqrt[3] (-8 + 
        Sqrt[3])] + (4 - (12 b (b (6 - (3 b (b - 4 s))/s^2) - 4 s))/
       s^2) Cosh[Sqrt[3] (-5 + Sqrt[3])]
   + (96 b (3 b^2 + s^2) Cosh[Sqrt[3] (-3 + Sqrt[3])])/s^3 - 
   4 (-1 - (3 b^2)/s^2)^2 Cosh[2 Sqrt[3] (-3 + Sqrt[3])] + 
   16 (-1 + (9 b^4)/s^4) Cosh[2 Sqrt[3] (-2 + Sqrt[3])] - 
   24 (-1 - (3 b^2)/s^2)^2 Cosh[
     Sqrt[3] (-1 + Sqrt[3])] - (32 (9 b^4 - 6 b^2 s^2 + s^4) Cosh[
        Sqrt[3] (-1 + Sqrt[3])]^2)/s^4;

Cases[exp, Cosh[a_] :> a, {1, ∞}] // 
 TakeLargestBy[#, Abs, 1] &
```

> {2 Sqrt[3] (-8 + Sqrt[3])}